# I want to read in written bits with python

Tags: python

I have a text file containing bits so it’s like „1000101011010110000…“ in this text. I want python to interpret this text as bytes and perform different byte transformations with it. But how do I red it on as bytes without python thinking it’s a string?

Comment: use `'rb'` flag for read in file

Comment: And what did you yourself do about it?

Comment: If you open the file as text, what you get *is* a string. If you see `1000101011010110000` in the string you get, then your file contains bits, but represented as the ascii characters 48 and 49, that is, `"0"` and `"1"` or `"\x30"` and `"\x31"`. It's  hard to imagine how you ended up with a file in such a format so it may be that your description is inaccurate or ambiguous. If it *is* in that format,  you can get it back to `0`s and `1`s like this: `list(x -48 for x in bytes (mystring,"ascii"))`. This will only work if your data is *precisely* as you describe it.

Answer (score 2):

[The built-in `int` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) has an parameter `base` for specifying the base.
To convert a string into an integer with base 2 (binary), pass 2 into it:

```py
s = input()
num = int(s, 2)
# Manipulate `num` as you like
```